# Android speech recognition intent: Listening for IP addresses

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I'm looking to use the Android Speech Recognition intent to listen for IP addresses for hands-free address entry. Experiments with it using the `LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM` have been less than successful; for some inputs, it's quite good---for example,

"one nine two dot one six eight dot one dot three"

... becomes...

`192. 168. 1. 4`

... and I can easily trim out the whitespace.

But it's flaky on numerical evaluation; for example,

"one nine two dot one six eight dot one dot four"

... becomes...

`192. 168. One. Four`

Is there a way to induce the speech recognizer to focus down to a particular subset of expected input (like IP addresses or just numbers and "dot")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: In the short run at least, I found it was pretty straightforward to check the input for instances of the full spellings of numbers and convert them to the numeric equivalence. Glass's on-board speech recognition was only problematic for a handful of numbers ("one" and "four" are the most common offenders).

Answer (score 1):

You can try CMUSphinx, an open source speech recognition toolkit

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid

It allows you to specify speech recognition grammar, with grammar it recognizes IP address with accuracy over 95%.